# Mapscript - PostGis Error

Tags: postgis, mapserver, mapscript

I'm doing a spatial query, but I always get an error:

> "msPOSTGISLayerGetShape(): Query
> error. msPOSTGISLayerGetShape called
> on unopened layer (layerinfo = NULL)"

This is my code:

```
layerObj layerUtbs = Util.MSMap.getLayerByName("Utbs");
if (layerUtbs.queryByRect(Util.MSMap, rect) == (int)MS_RETURN_VALUE.MS_SUCCESS)
{
    resultCacheObj resultado = layerUtbs.getResults();

    if (resultado.numresults > 0)
    {
        // here i got a error.
        layerUtbs.getFeature(resultado.getResult(0).shapeindex, resultado.getResult(0).tileindex);
    }
}
```

Here's my map file configuration

```
LAYER 
        CONNECTIONTYPE postgis 
        NAME "Utbs" 
        CONNECTION "user=pmc dbname=SiteInovacao host=localhost password=123 port=5432"
        PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"     
        DATA "geom from (SELECT *, oid FROM pmc.utbs) as utbs using unique oid using srid=31983"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its basically telling you whats wrong- you have not 'opened' the layer
Try this:

```
if (resultado.numresults > 0)
            {
                // Open layer
                layerUtbs.open();

                // here i got a error (you shouldn't now);.
                layerUtbs.getFeature(resultado.getResult(0).shapeindex, resultado.getResult(0).tileindex);
        }
    }
```